Usage of an Inappropriate Analogy in a Comment on a Question
I was cruising over the comments on this question when I noticed this comment that quoted an inappropriate analogy, albeit the quote is true. Should such kind of references be allowed, or is it fine as long as it is valid and relevant to the question?

The comment was gratuitous natter, so I deleted it along with some others.  The analogy made by Feynman in the quote is crude, but discussion of sex is not automatically off limits.  However, sexual matters are not commonly going to be relevant on this particular stack.
